# Replace the node of Beautiful Soup with string in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have to download and save the webpages with a given URL. I have downloaded the page as well as the required js and css files. But the problem is to change the src and href values of those tags in the html source file as well to make it work.

my html source is :

```
<link REL="shortcut icon" href="/commd/favicon.ico">
<script src="/commd/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/commd/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/commd/slimScroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/commd/ajaxstuff.js"></script>
<script src="/commd/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>FCT0505
<script src="/commd/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fonts/stylesheet.cssFCT0505"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/commd/stylesheet.css"/>
<!--[if gte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/commd/stylesheetIE.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/commd/accordion.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/commd/nivo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/commd/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I have found out all the links of css and js files as well as downloaded them using :

```
scriptsurl = soup3.find_all("script")
        os.chdir(foldername)
        for l in scriptsurl:
            if l.get("src") is not None:
                print(l.get("src"))
                script="http://www.iitkgp.ac.in"+l.get("src")
                print(script)
                file=l.get("src").split("/")[-1]
                l.get("src").replaceWith('./foldername/'+file)
                print(file)
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(script,file)
        linksurl=soup3.find_all("link")
        for l in linksurl:
            if l.get("href") is not None:
                print(l.get("href"))
                css="http://www.iitkgp.ac.in"+l.get("href")
                file=l.get("href").split("/")[-1]
                print(css)
                print(file)
                if(os.path.exists(file)):
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(css,file.split(".")[0]+"(1)."+file.split(".")[-1])
                else:
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(css,file)
os.chdir("..")
```

Can anyone suggest me the method to change(local machine path) the the src/href texts during these loop executions only which will be great help.
This is my first task of crawling.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

> You can add, remove, and modify a tag’s attributes. Again, this is done by treating the tag as a dictionary:

So writing something like:

```
l["src"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),foldername, file)
```

instead of

```
l.get("src").replaceWith('./foldername/'+file)
```

I believe will do the trick

Comment: giving an error :
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'replaceWith'

Comment: Right, I didn't realise that `foldername` was a variable. And you got me carried away ;) Why did you write `replaceWith` at first place? You tried to write pseudocode? Check the edited answer